# Len e Max Float juntos Python

Tags: python

Estou tentando descobrir o índice do maior número da lista e adicionar o número do índice em uma variável, mas está dando um erro de `float`, de que lista não pode ser executada com `float`. Como posso corrigir isso?

```
nome = 0
altura = 0
alturas = []
nomes = []
quant = 0

while True:
    nome = input('Nome da moça: ').upper()
    if nome == 'FIM':
        break
    elif nome != 'FIM':
        nomes.append(nome)
        altura = input('Altura da moça: ')
        alturas.append(float(altura))
        quant += +1
maior = len(max(alturas))
```

Comment: Você não precisa do `len`. length (cumprimento) é uma função definida para coleções (quantos elementos tem uma lista, quantos valores tem uma tuple etc). Um float é apenas um número

Answer (score 3):

o `len` serve para você obter o tamanho da lista e não o índice de um valor. O que você quer fazer é achar o índice do máximo, mas você precisa ter cuidado porque podem existir mais de um máximo (duas alturas com o mesmo valor). Se você só estiver interessado na primeira aparição do máximo pode usar o `lista.index` assim:

```
maior = alturas.index(max(alturas))
```

se você quiser pergar todos pode fazer assim:

```
maximo = max(alturas)
maiores = [indice for indice, valor in enumerate(alturas) if valor == maximo]
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem uma lista qualquer (não necessariamente digitada pelo usuário), pode usar a solução da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/484653/112052).

Mas no seu caso específico, em que o usuário vai digitando os dados, é possível já calcular tudo no mesmo *loop* que lê as informações:

```
alturas = []
nomes = []
maior = float('-inf')
i = 0
while True:
    nome = input('Nome da moça: ').upper()
    if nome == 'FIM':
        break
    nomes.append(nome)
    altura = float(input('Altura da moça: '))
    if altura > maior:
        maior = altura
        indice_maior = i
    alturas.append(altura)
    i += 1

print(f'Maior altura é {maior}, e está no índice {indice_maior}')
```

Repare que você não precisa criar as variáveis `nome` e `altura` antes do `while`, com algum valor artificial qualquer. Elas podem ser criadas dentro do *loop*, somente quando forem necessárias.

E o `if nome == 'FIM'` não precisa de `else`. Pois se entrar no `if` ele chama `break`, que sai do `while` (ou seja, não vai executar o restante). E se não entrar no `if`, é porque com certeza não foi digitado "FIM", então um `elif` para testar isso de novo é redundante.

A ideia é que, conforme os valores vão sendo lidos, eu já verifico se ele é o maior, e guardo também o respectivo índice.

---

Mas temos que ver também os casos de empate, conforme indicado na outra resposta. Outro detalhe é que, se os nomes e alturas estão relacionados, talvez fosse melhor guardá-los juntos em vez de ter listas separadas. Uma opção é criar tuplas contendo o nome e a respectiva altura:

```
maior = float('-inf')
dados = []
while True:
    nome = input('Nome da moça: ').upper()
    if nome == 'FIM':
        break
    altura = float(input('Altura da moça: '))
    if altura > maior:
        maior = altura
    dados.append((nome, altura)) # insere uma tupla contendo o nome e altura

# ou no caso de empate
print(f'Pessoas mais altas, com {maior} de altura:')
for i, (nome, altura) in enumerate(dados):
    if altura == maior:
        print(f'índice {i} = {nome}')
```

Repare que agora só tem uma lista, contendo todos os dados. E cada elemento é uma tupla, contendo o nome e a respectiva altura.

Para inserir eu fiz `dados.append((nome, altura))`. Pode parecer que tem parênteses a mais, mas não: se eu fizesse apenas `dados.append(nome, altura)`, daria erro porque assim estou passando 2 parâmetros para `append`, que só aceita um. Ao colocar outro par de parênteses, estou dizendo que quero inserir a tupla `(nome, altura)` na lista.

No `while` eu continuo verificando o maior à medida em que leio os dados, e depois eu percorro a lista e imprimo os nomes e índices das pessoas mais altas (assim, em caso de empate, você tem todas).